# Help with query for SharePoint (online) Lists.GetListItems

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I am trying to get customers with a matching name from a SharePoint list
I tried with:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("<Query><Where><Lt><FieldRef Name=\"CustomerName\"/><Value Type=\"Text\">" + customerName + "</Value></Lt></Where></Query>");
XmlNode listQuery = doc.SelectSingleNode("//Query");

XmlNode n = sharePoint.listsObj.GetListItems(listName, null, listQuery, null, null, null, null);
nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(n.OwnerDocument.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("z", "#RowsetSchema");
nsmgr.AddNamespace("rs", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset");
XmlNodeList itemNodeList = n.SelectNodes("rs:data/z:row", nsmgr);
```

But in itemNodeList I get a customer with a name that is not similar at all to the parameter (customerName) I use in the query.

If I don't pass on the query I get all customers from the list.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get names that match exactly then use the Eq tag

For example from

- Smith
- Smith-Jones
- Jones

the following

```
<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="CustomerName"/><Value Type="Text">Smith</Value></Eq></Where></Query>
```

would return

- Smith

If you want to return names that contain the string then use the Contains tag

```
<Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name="CustomerName"/><Value Type="Text">Smith</Value></Contains></Where></Query>
```

would return

- Smith-Jones
- Jones

Have a look at the U2U CAML Builder

http://www.u2u.net/res/Tools/CamlQueryBuilder.aspx

Comment: Yeah I just realized I could use Eq but Contains is better, thanks. Good link, what does Gt and Lt stand for?

Comment: Greater Than and Less Than which would normally apply to number based queries.